# EF query on specific table queries db with ModelStoreConatiner name as Schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a Database-First EF 6.2 c# application.
I created a derived class from InterfaceMI_Entities to set the connection string so that I can use the following code to set up a context:

```
using (var ctx = new InterfaceMI_Entities(server, database))
```

When I make a call to one table (ma_parm) using LINQ, the following query is generated:

```
SELECT 
    <list of columns>
    FROM [InterfaceMI_ModelStoreContainer].[MA_PARM] AS [Extent1]
```

The EntityContainer in the edmx file is set up as follows:

```
<EntityContainer Name="InterfaceMI_ModelStoreContainer">
   <EntitySet Name="MA_PARM" EntityType="Self.MA_PARM" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo">
          </EntitySet>
   <EntitySet Name="MA_PARM_LAND" EntityType="Self.MA_PARM_LAND" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="dbo">
          </EntitySet>
```

The query for MA_PARM_LAND works, but MA_PARM uses the EntityContainer as the schema name.

Any ideas as to why the EntityContainer is being used as the schema exclusively for the MA_PARM table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this was happening, but changing

```
store:Schema="dbo"
```

to

```
Schema="dbo"
```

resolved the issue.

Comment: How was this EDMX generated/edited later? `store:Schema="dbo"` is always used in combination with `store:Type="Views"`, not `store:Type="Tables"`, so it's weird that your EDMX contained this element.

Comment: I opened the edmx diagram up, right-clicked and updated the model from the database.  The generated model had defining queries generated on the tables.  For any of the tables that required insert/update functionality I removed the defining queries and changed the store:Schema => Schema.